# How Can I Access the Data From an AJAX call that sends JSON Data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am experimenting with ajax calls. What i am doing is passing a list of objects to the controller via an ajax call. Automatic model binding works fine but what i am trying to do is to get the json string manually reading from an input stream but my solution does not work.
Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = [{ Data1: "data1", Data2: 1, Data3: 41 },
    { Data1: "data2", Data2: 12, Data3: 42 },
    { Data1: "data3", Data2: 13, Data3: 43 }
    ];

    $("#PassList").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/PassList',
            data: JSON.stringify(data) ,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success passing List");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PassList(List<SampleData> SampleDatas, string NewData)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
        string line = "";
        line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You should do a `console.log` data in the `success` callback of the ajax call and check the response. That should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default model binder is working properly becauseyou set:

**`contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`** in your ajax call.

To get the json string manually reading from an input stream, **comment these 2 lines in your ajax:**

```
// contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
// dataType: 'html',
```

On the controller side, you'll have:

```
public ActionResult PassList()
{
     System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
     string line = "";
     line = sr.ReadToEnd();
     return View();
}
```